# Overlapping TextBlocks: Why?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

This code is supposed to produce a 4 x 3 grid of notes. The TextBlocks overlap once produced. **The padding was an attempt at adjustment: Fail.**

Code:

**PivotPage.xaml**:

```
<Page>
    <Grid>
        <Pivot x:Uid="Pivot" Title="MY APPLICATION" x:Name="pivot" CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True">
            <!--Pivot item one-->
            <PivotItem
                x:Uid="PivotItem1"
                Margin="19,14.5,0,0"
                CommonNavigationTransitionInfo.IsStaggerElement="True">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding strings}">
                        <!--
                    -->
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="4" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="64" Padding="27,0"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Box It!"/>
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

UPDATE: Picture

[image: This is usually worse to the point where they're nearly on top of each other.]

Comment: can you show UI? @sage

Comment: @Aravin: Try now. It used to be worse, but I guess the padding  helped  a little. Remove the padding, though, and they're slightly on top of each other.

Comment: I don't see any overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue, but there's a caveat to it.

First the answer:

**PivotPage.xaml**:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="64" Margin="24,20"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Change it from "Padding" to "Margin", adjust the size a little, and it's fixed.

Also:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Make Height "Auto", so the row for the button doesn't keep moving around.

The caveat to this is that the size of Grid will vary each time you run the program. For that reason, I suggest (to myself) to do something more like this:

```
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                                   Text="{Binding Notes[0],FallbackValue=B♭}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontSize="64"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                                   Text="{Binding Notes[1],FallbackValue=B♭}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontSize="64"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" 
                                   Text="{Binding Notes[2],FallbackValue=B♭}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontSize="64"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                                   Text="{Binding Notes[3],FallbackValue=B♭}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontSize="64"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                                   Text="{Binding Notes[4],FallbackValue=B♭}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontSize="64"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" 
                                   Text="{Binding Notes[5],FallbackValue=B♭}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontSize="64"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" 
                                   Text="{Binding Notes[6],FallbackValue=B♭}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontSize="64"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
                                   Text="{Binding Notes[7],FallbackValue=B♭}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontSize="64"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" 
                                   Text="{Binding Notes[8],FallbackValue=B♭}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontSize="64"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" 
                                   Text="{Binding Notes[9],FallbackValue=B♭}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontSize="64"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" 
                                   Text="{Binding Notes[10],FallbackValue=B♭}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontSize="64"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" 
                                   Text="{Binding Notes[11],FallbackValue=B♭}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontSize="64"/>
                    </Grid>
```

It may be frowned upon, but with only twelve notes, you won't be doing this much, and it will guarantee the the grid stays the same size each time the app is run.

I'm still looking for better solutions, so if you have one, please feel free to say so. This is a temporary answer until I can get something better.

By the way: replaced "strings" with "Notes" for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using padding(which provides inner spacing to the element in question) use Margins(they provide outer spacing to the elements in question.)

Will solve your problem instantly